# For Loop doesn't spit out needed results

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I got this piece of code to spit out the unique "area number" in the URL. However, the loop doesn't work. It spits out the same number, please see below:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = open('MS Type 1 URL.txt',encoding='utf-8-sig')

links = []
for link in url:
    y = link.strip()
    links.append(y)

url.close()

print('Amount of Links: ', len(links))

for x in links:
    j = (x.find("=") + 1)
    g = (x.find('&housing'))
    print(link[j:g])
```

Results are:

http://millersamuel.com/aggy-data/home/query_report?area=38&housing_type=3&measure=4&query_type=quarterly&region=1&year_end=2020&year_start=1980
23

http://millersamuel.com/aggy-data/home/query_report?area=23&housing_type=1&measure=4&query_type=annual&region=1&year_end=2020&year_start=1980
23

As you can see it spits out the area number '23' which is only in one of this URL but not the '38' of the other URL.

Comment: Fixed loop: `for link in links:`.

Comment: `print(x[j:g])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your code. You iterate over `links` list and bind its elements to `x` variable, but print a slice of `link` variable, so you get the same string printed on each loop iteration. So you can change `print(link[j:g])` to `print(x[j:g])`, but it's better to call your variables with more descriptive names, so here's the fixed version of your loop:

```
for link in links:
    j = link.find('=') + 1
    g = link.find('&housing')
    print(link[j:g])
```

And I also want to show you a proper way to extract `area` value from URLs:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
url = 'http://millersamuel.com/aggy-data/home/query_report?area=38&housing_type=3&measure=4&query_type=quarterly&region=1&year_end=2020&year_start=1980'
area = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['area'][0]
```

So instead of using `str.find` method, you can write this:

```
for url in urls:
    parsed_qs = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
    if 'area' in parsed_qs:
        area = parsed_qs['area'][0]
        print(area)
```

Used functions:

- [`urllib.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse)
- [`urllib.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to change:

```
print(link[j:g]) to print(x[j:g])
```